# Not getting the xml file output

Tags: python

I am trying to read the xml file `email.xml`(Data below) using the python code provided below,am not able to print the actual data present in the xml file but getting the below output. Where am I going wrong?

**CURRENT OUTPUT**:

```
xmlfile
<open file 'email.xml', mode 'r' at 0x0226AF98>
[<DOM Element: to at 0x231d620>]
[<DOM Element: cc at 0x231d6c0>]
[<DOM Element: bcc at 0x231d760>]
```

**PYTHON CODE**:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom

def getemaildata():
    # Open the XML file
    xmlfile = open('email.xml','r')
    print "xmlfile"
    print xmlfile
    dom = minidom.parse(xmlfile)
    email=dom.getElementsByTagName('email')
    for node in email:
        toemail=dom.getElementsByTagName('to')
        print toemail
        ccemail=dom.getElementsByTagName('cc')
        print ccemail
        bccemail=dom.getElementsByTagName('bcc')
        print bccemail
return (toemail,ccemail,bccemail)

def main ():
(To,CC,BCC)=getemaildata()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

**`email.xml` file**:

```
<email>
    <to>data@company.com;data.stability@company.com; 
         data.sns@company.com;data.pes@company.com;</to> 
    <cc> data.team </cc>
    <bcc>data@company.com</bcc>     
</email>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting back lists of "Element" objects from the XML parser. You need to iterate further to get to the actual "Text" nodes.

Eg:

```
# this returns a list of all Elements that have the tag "to"
toemail=dom.getElementsByTagName('to')

# Here we take the first node returned with tag 'to', then it's first child node
textnode = toemail[0].childNodes[0]

# print the data in the textnode
print textnode.data
```

To clean the addresses from the text node:

```
for address in textnode.data.split(';'):
    if address == '':
        # Catch empty entries as a result of trailing ;
        continue
    email = i.strip().strip('\n')
    print email
```

Comment: thanks..how to format the data..I see the data is getting printed as is without any formatting like http://pastie.org/5398584

Comment: i tried to split and join using ";" but still the same        tolist=textnode.data.split(';')
        print ";".join(tolist)

Comment: XML will store exactly what is between the two tags, so you can either ensure that your input XML is sanitised (whitespace and newlines removed), or perform the sanitising on every address. I've added an edit to my answer to show how this cold be done. Ideally your email addresses would each be stored in their own tag, rather than being bundled together, but I'm guessing your input XML data is coming from email headers, so it might not be possible for you to get your data in a better way.